# Client side events not working after creating a wrapper over Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker, telerik-datepicker

I have a wrapper class over RadDatePicker.

```
public class DateTimePicker : Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker
{
    public DateTimePicker ()
        : base()
    {
        //
        // Some code her
        //
    }
}
```

Now, I have my own implementation here. I want to use the event's like `DateInput-ClientEvents-OnBlur` :

```
<mydll:DateTimePicker id="date" runat="server" autopostback="true" 
       DateInput-ClientEvents-OnBlur="alert('Ding');"/>
```

But, I couldn't get the `OnBlur` working. Not getting what did I miss.

Thanks.
IO

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or MVC?  Are you trying to bind the event in markup only, or could you use JavaScript or C#/VB.NET server-side to set it?

Comment: 1) It is ASP.NET. 2) I am trying to bind event in markup only.